# How to add custom code on workflow state change?

Tags: pipelines, workflow, events

Is there a pipeline / event available which I can plug into to execute custom code when workflow state changes for any item?

Comment: How is this question different from https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/14071/which-pipeline-is-used-to-change-the-workflow-state-internally ? Can you be more specific about your issue, otherwise this one might be marked as duplicate..

Comment: The question is different because the previous question is how to change workflow states programmatically.. This is asking how to execute code when a workflow state is changed.

Comment: Indeed - luckily @PeteNavarra is more awake than I am :)

Answer (score 7):

There's no pipeline or event that you can plug into in the general sense of Sitecore's pipelines and events that you see in the ShowConfig.  Instead, it's driven by an Item based pipeline provider.

This is accomplished by creating what's called **Workflow Actions** that allows you to execute code when a workflow is changed to that state.

There's an example of this in the Standard Workflow that comes with Sitecore.

[image]

1) Create a new item under the Workflow State that you want the action to execute on using the `/sitecore/templates/System/Workflow/Action` template.

2) Create your Custom Code like the `PublishAction`.

```
  public class PublishAction
  {
    /// <summary>Runs the processor.</summary>
    /// <param name="args">The arguments.</param>
    public void Process(WorkflowPipelineArgs args)
    {
      Item dataItem = args.DataItem;
      Item innerItem = args.ProcessorItem.InnerItem;
      NameValueCollection urlParameters = WebUtil.ParseUrlParameters(innerItem["parameters"]);
      bool deep = this.GetDeep(urlParameters, innerItem);
      bool related = this.GetRelated(urlParameters, innerItem);
      Database[] array1 = this.GetTargets(urlParameters, innerItem, dataItem).ToArray<Database>();
      Language[] array2 = this.GetLanguages(urlParameters, innerItem, dataItem).ToArray<Language>();
      bool compareRevisions = this.IsCompareRevision(urlParameters, innerItem);
      if (!Settings.Publishing.Enabled || !((IEnumerable<Database>) array1).Any<Database>() || !((IEnumerable<Language>) array2).Any<Language>())
        return;
      PublishManager.PublishItem(dataItem, array1, array2, deep, compareRevisions, related);
    }
  }
```

3) Set the Namespace and Class name of your custom code to the **Type string** field.

4) ???

5) Profit!  Now when an item changes to that workflow state, the custom code will execute.

Comment: _Technically_ it _is_ a "pipeline", just the database version. https://sitecorerap.wordpress.com/2018/05/31/hidden-in-plain-sight-configure-a-pipeline-with-sitecore-items-no-config-changes/

Comment: That's fair. It's just not seen as much...  since you don't see it in the ShowConfig like other pipelines.  But you are not wrong.